# Call Asynctask in Android fragments is slow

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm trying to load an activity with 3 fragments. For each fragment, i use and Asynctask, and on the onPostExecute() methods of each of them, i load Ui elements. The problem is that when i swipe from fragments to fragments when the Asynctask is loading the ui elements, the application is really slow. I've tried to get rid of this problem by calling onUiThread(), it decreased the slow a little bit. the Asynctasks are used in the onCreateView methods of the fragments.

What can i do to get rid of this lag ?

Here's one Asynctask :

```
public class MovieCommentsAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private String TAG = "MovieCommentsAsynctask";
private Context context;
private boolean test;
private HttpClient client;
private List<MovieCommentsObject> comments;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;
//
private RelativeLayout rl;
private ProgressBar pb;
private PullToRefreshScrollView sv;
private LinearLayout ll;
private Button btn;

public MovieCommentsAsynctask(Context context, RelativeLayout rl,
        boolean test, Activity activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.rl = rl;
    this.test = test;
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    bind();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private void bind() {
    ll = (LinearLayout) rl.findViewById(R.id.ll_fragment_movie_comments);
    sv = (PullToRefreshScrollView) rl
            .findViewById(R.id.sv_fragment_movie_comments);
    pb = (ProgressBar) rl.findViewById(R.id.pb_fragment_movie_comments);
    btn = (Button) rl.findViewById(R.id.btn_fragment_movie_comments_add);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    if (test) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    String url = params[0];
    BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        return client.execute(get, handler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (result != null && result.startsWith("[")) {
        Log.i(TAG, "restult = " + result);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<MovieCommentsObject>>() {
        }.getType();
        comments = gson.fromJson(result, type);
        init();
    }
}

private void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++) {
        MovieCommentsObject comment = comments.get(i);
        addComment(comment);
    }
    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void addComment(final MovieCommentsObject comment) {

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_movie_comments, null);
            SmartImageView siv = (SmartImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.siv_adapter_movie_comments);
            WebView wv_user = (WebView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.wv_adapter_movie_comments_user);
            WebView wv_date = (WebView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.wv_adapter_movie_comments_date);

            WebView wv_text = (WebView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.wv_adapter_movie_comments_text);
            TextView tv_type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_movie_comments_type);
            wv_text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            wv_user.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            wv_date.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            long date = comment.getInserted();
            if (date > 0) {
                FunctionsGeneral.justify(wv_date, FunctionsGeneral.getTime(date));
            }
            FunctionsGeneral.justify(wv_user, comment.getUser().getUsername());
            FunctionsGeneral.justify(wv_text, comment.getText_html());
            String image = comment.getUser().getAvatar();
            if (image != null && image.trim().length() > 0) {
                siv.setImageUrl(image);
            }
            if(comment.getType() != null){
                tv_type.setText(comment.getType());
            }
            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.bottomMargin = 10;
            ll.addView(v, params);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: are you actually creating UI objects in your onPostExecute or are you just populating data of already existing views?

Comment: In one of i'm populating a gridview, and in another one i'm create views and add them to a layout (already there).

Comment: You might want to post some code showing what you're doing

Comment: I've edited my post with the Asynctask that create UI objects.

Comment: Why don't you create and return your Comments list in your Async task? Whats the point of the async task if you're still doing heavy lifting on the UI thread once you download the data? Processing of JSON is not fast/light-weight and you should do that in your doInBackground call. Change your async tasks return type to List<MovieCommentsObject>

Comment: what should i put inside the doInBackground ?

Comment: You can put comments = gson.fromJson(result, type); into doInBackground. Also, seems that addComment() method is really not effective. It mmight be better to use ListView for comments.

Comment: I'm facing same problem.. Asynctask too much slow under fragment.. I'm using ViewPager so there are so many Fragment under this viewpager.. One more problem is call all fragment at once under this viewpager load... How to solve it?